# Determine if values are +/-10% of each other in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, range, parameters

Hello and thank you in advance. I'm trying to put together a formula to determine if a series of values, e.g., 22.1, 23.4, 22.5 (up to 12 different numbers) are within +/-10% of each other. I've tried variations of the following, but to no avail:

=IF(ABS(B1-A1)/MAX(ABS(B1),ABS(A1))>0.1,"out of limits","within limits")

=if(or(and(x>=a,x<=b),and(a>=x,a<=y)),"Overlap","Do not overlap")

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to know if each number is within 10% of the largest number, the smallest number, the average number, or something else?

Comment: To add to the possibilities Blackwood mentioned, the question describes all numbers being within 10% of each other, which describes "worst case".  Also, the question uses a formula that compares a single pair of cells.  How did you envision using this to evaluate the whole list?

Answer (score 1):

For all values to be within 10% of each other, the maximum value must be no more than 10% greater than the minimum value.  So you don't need to play with ABS or compare every value to every other value, just compare those two values.  The formula in C1:

```
=IF(MAX(A:A)/MIN(A:A)>1.1,"out of limit","within limit")
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the question seems to use a rule of "10% of the larger value" while you have 10% of the smaller value.  Straightforward to fix if the values are positive, just `MIN(A:A)/MAX(A:A)<0.9`.  If the values are negative, though, the roles of min and max will swap.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the question says "within +/-10% of each other", so I based the answer on that.  The OP attempted to achieve that by comparing to the max, but I assumed that was simply a misguided solution; they said their efforts were unsuccessful, so I just ignored the detail of their formula.  Blackwood has asked for clarification.  Hopefully, the OP will provide it.  Then we can get the question wording clarified and adjust answers if needed.  But yeah, it's good that people are being observant about the inconsistencies so we can get them cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
=IF(MAX(ABS(1-(B1/A1)),ABS(1-(A1/B1)))<0.1,"OK","out of limits")
```

Comment: suppose that a1=b1=0

Comment: @Jasen, sigh. Yes, every division will fail when the numbers are all zeros. That is not the question. Working out all the error traps would confuse the issue more than it will help. Suppose the numbers are not zero.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this:

```
    =if(xor(A1*11>=B1*10,B1*11<A1*10),"good","bad")
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that the best answers teach you something. This could be improved my explaining how this formula works and how it applies to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume that Data is in the Range A1:A10.

   - Criteria : If the Current is More than 10 % Of Earlier Then it is said to be OUT.
2. In Cell B2 enter the Formula :

   - `= IF (  ( Max(A1:A2)/Min(A1:A2 ) >  1.1,   "OUT", "WITHIN" )`
3. Copy the Formula of B2 down the Cells B3, B4, B5,....

Note : If the Order of Occurrence is not important, It is better to Sort the Data before the test. Because otherwise due to One Outlier, Two becomes " OUT ".